# Choosing the second highest row in an index set

Tags: excel

Currently have a data set that looks like this

```
ID Function  UniqueID
1  .8        11
1  .77       12
1  .75       13
2  .8        21
2  .8        22
2  .75       23
```

I am attempting to grab the **first row** of each "ID" set **only** when the **second** highest row in that ID set has a function value **LESS THAN** the highest row

In this instance I want output of
`UniqueID: 11`

Answer (score 0):

With Excel 365, you could try

```
 =LET(matches,MATCH(A2:A7,A2:A7,0),FILTER(C2:C7,(INDEX(B2:B7,matches)>INDEX(B2:B7,matches+1))*(ROW(A2:A7)-1=matches)*(COUNTIF(A2:A7,A2:A7)>1)))
```

assuming that the values are sorted in descending order in each ID group and that the data starts in row 2.

[image]

So this compares the value in the first row of each group with the value in the second row, selects only the first row of each group and also checks that there are at least two values in the group to compare.